# JQuery:nothing is loaded into iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I took this code from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/292wF/)
and it's working on that but when I tried to use it on my site it doesn't work

you can see my page [here](http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/dropdown.html)(or run the snippet below) it seems like nothing being loaded into iframe

and my short code below

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>DROPDOWN</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body style="width:880px">

<select id="selector">
    <option value="0">select year</option>
    <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2000.html">2000</option>
 <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2005.html">2005</option>
 <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2008.html">2008</option>
 <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2010.html">2010</option>
 <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2015.html">2015</option>
   
</select>
<div>
    <iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0" id="iframeId"></iframe>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selector").change(function(){
        $("#iframeId").attr("src", $(this).val());
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

anyone please help,I'm a starter for coding,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to use one `script` tag to both link to JQuery and to embed your page script. A single `<script>` element can be used to link to an external script:

```
<script src="PATH HERE"></script>
```

...or to embed an internal script:

```
<script>
  // Code here
</script>
```

...but not both at once.

By simply closing the external script and then opening another one for your page level script, the code works.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>DROPDOWN</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body style="width:880px">

<select id="selector">
    <option value="0">select year</option>
    <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2000.html">2000</option>
 <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2005.html">2005</option>
 <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2008.html">2008</option>
 <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2010.html">2010</option>
 <option value="http://www.sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/takeback_policymap_2015.html">2015</option>
   
</select>
<div>
    <iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0" id="iframeId"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- A script tag can be used to reference an external script, like this: -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Or, an internal script, like this:  -->
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selector").change(function(){
        $("#iframeId").attr("src", $(this).val());
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the down vote for the correct answer that shows the working code?